# How to run teardown function / fixture after parametrize

Tags: python, parameters, automated-tests, pytest, fixtures

I am trying to run teardown function / fixture for whole parametrization of one testcase. So I want to have in my conftest.py file something like this

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="parametrization")
def parametrization_scope():
    print("First run of parametrization fixture")
    # Executing 100 parametrizations
    yield
    print("Yield run of parametrization fixture")
```

and in my test.py something like

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(n-params)
# run initiate fixture here of parametrization
def test():
    # executing n number of times

# run yield fixture here of parametrization
```

Comment: Put the code for teardown after `yield` in the fixture.

Comment: Yeah, that would work if there was scope 'parametrization'. 'function' scope runs before/after each test case run, 'module' scope before/after whole module/file run, and 'session' scope is used to run before/after whole session run. What I need is only before/after of parametrization

Comment: Is `parametrization` even a valid scope?

Comment: It is not. I just gave an example of what I am trying to succeed here. So, similiar behavior with other fixture scopes. I have made some workaround of it to give my last configuration ( list[-1]) an key with name 'last_run' and its value set to 'True' and inspecting existance of such key in test case and than executing teardown function if the 'last_run' is True....

Comment: Parametrization is simply taken just a copying of your test function `n` times, done in the test collection phase, and there are no explicit entrypoints before and after a test parametrization.

Comment: What you can do though is implement your custom logic in hooks: [`pytest_sessionstart`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionstart) is called before test collection (and thus also parametrization) runs, and [`pytest_runtestloop`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtestloop) is called after test collection has finished (and all tests are parametrized), but before the actual test execution starts.

Comment: Well, this would be good if I need to run function only once or I miss understood. If I implement hook into [pytest_sessionstart] it will run only once before test collection of, in my case, n files with n parametrizations in them. [pytest_runtestloop] is also executed only once after whole collection. What I need is to run function after each last run of n parametrizations in the n modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a test class to workaround the missing "parametrization" scope like this:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def foo():
    print("setup")
    yield None
    print("teardown")

class TestSum:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "a,b,c",
        [(3, 5, 8), (2, 4, 6)],
    )
    def test_eval(self, a, b, c, foo):
        assert a + b == c
```

If only the TestSum class uses the fixture foo, you could even place the definition of foo inside the class.

Comment: Whoa, @bnjmnp, nice idea and solution. Sadly, I have already resolved this in another way of testing logic which did not require this. But still, nice solution :)

Comment: @MaxZix and now your going to be magnanimous and share your solution?