# pytest: run class scoped parametrized fixture's dependency fixture's teardown after each test class iteration

Tags: python, pytest

**Problem:**

The `conftest.py` fixture's setup/teardown needs to run after each test class iteration but NOT after each individual test invocation within the class.

When running `pytest test_foo.py --setup-plan`, the `SETUP C conf_fixt` is only executed before the first parametrized class iteration, and `TEARDOWN C conf_fixt` is only executed after the last parameterized class iteration is complete.

**Related Files:**

`conftest.py`

```
import pytest
from random import randint

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def conf_fixt():
    y = randint(1, 100000)
    yield y
    print(f'teardown: {y}')
```

`test_foo.py`

```
from buildspecs.foo.conftest import conf_fixt
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("scenario", [
    ("scenario_1"),
    ("scenario_2")
], scope='class')

class TestZoo:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def scenario_1(self):
        yield 'scenario_1'

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def scenario_2(self):
        yield 'scenario_2'

    def test_scenario(self, scenario, request, conf_fixt):
        print(f'scenario value: {request.getfixturevalue(scenario)}')
        print(f'conf_fixt value: {conf_fixt}')

    def test_other(self, scenario, request, conf_fixt):
        print(f'scenario value: {request.getfixturevalue(scenario)}')
        print(f'conf_fixt value: {conf_fixt}')
```

Actual:

`pytest test_foo.py`

```
platform linux -- Python 3.9.8, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /src
plugins: mock-3.6.1
collected 4 items                                                                                   

test_foo.py scenario value: scenario_1
conf_fixt value: 111111
.scenario value: scenario_1
conf_fixt value: 111111
.scenario value: scenario_2
conf_fixt value: 111111
.scenario value: scenario_2
conf_fixt value: 111111
.teardown: 111111
```

`pytest test_foo.py --setup-plan`

```
platform linux -- Python 3.9.8, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /src
plugins: mock-3.6.1
collected 2 items                                                                                   

test_foo.py 
      SETUP    C conf_fixt
      SETUP    C scenario['scenario_1']
        buildspecs/foo/test_foo.py::TestZoo::test_scenario[scenario_1] (fixtures used: conf_fixt, request, scenario)
      TEARDOWN C scenario['scenario_1']
      SETUP    C scenario['scenario_2']
        buildspecs/foo/test_foo.py::TestZoo::test_scenario[scenario_2] (fixtures used: conf_fixt, request, scenario)
      TEARDOWN C scenario['scenario_2']
      TEARDOWN C conf_fixt
```

Expected:

`pytest test_foo.py`

```
platform linux -- Python 3.9.8, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /src
plugins: mock-3.6.1
collected 4 items                                                                                   

test_foo.py scenario value: scenario_1
conf_fixt value: 111111
.scenario value: scenario_1
conf_fixt value: 111111
.teardown: 111111
.scenario value: scenario_2
conf_fixt value: 222222
.scenario value: scenario_2
conf_fixt value: 222222
.teardown: 222222
```

`pytest test_foo.py --setup-plan`

```
platform linux -- Python 3.9.8, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /src
plugins: mock-3.6.1
collected 2 items                                                                                   

test_foo.py 
      SETUP    C conf_fixt
      SETUP    C scenario['scenario_1']
        buildspecs/foo/test_foo.py::TestZoo::test_scenario[scenario_1] (fixtures used: conf_fixt, request, scenario)
      TEARDOWN C scenario['scenario_1']
      ###Expected teardown
      TEARDOWN C conf_fixt 
      ###
      SETUP    C scenario['scenario_2']
        buildspecs/foo/test_foo.py::TestZoo::test_scenario[scenario_2] (fixtures used: conf_fixt, request, scenario)
      TEARDOWN C scenario['scenario_2']
      TEARDOWN C conf_fixt
```

**Solution Preferences:**

- `conf_fixt` not defined within the `TestZoo` class.

**Attempts:**

Add the `conf_fixt` fixture to the `pytest.marks.parametrize()` decorator like so:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("scenario,conf_fixt_param", [
    ("scenario_1", "conf_fixt"),
    ("scenario_2", "conf_fixt")
], scope='class')

class TestZoo:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def scenario_1(self):
        yield 'scenario_1'

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def scenario_2(self):
        yield 'scenario_2'

    def test_scenario(self, scenario, request, conf_fixt_param):
        print(f'scenario value: {request.getfixturevalue(scenario)}')
        print(f'conf_fixt value: {request.getfixturevalue(conf_fixt_param)}')


    def test_other(self, scenario, request, conf_fixt_param):
        print(f'scenario value: {request.getfixturevalue(scenario)}')
        print(f'conf_fixt value: {request.getfixturevalue(conf_fixt_param)}')
```

Same Actual and Expected output as the original problem.

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as "test class iteration" - parametrization just creates additional tests inside the same class, so a class-scoped fixture won't help you here.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thank you for the clarification. If only there was a scope="parametrization" arg within @pytest.fixture() that would allow for specific setups/teardowns for each value within the parametrization decorator as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492529/how-to-run-teardown-function-fixture-after-parametrize

Comment: Would be nice, but I guess this would be difficult to implement and does not really fit into pytest. I don't have a solution here (other than using a function-scoped fixture which checks the test names itself and only does something if the parameter changes, which is quite ugly).